# where is the code for all the rally charts given on "View Reports and Charts? "

Tags: rally

I see that there are lot of charts given [here](https://help.rallydev.com/status-reports#arrival) on the "View Reports and Charts" page. Where is the code for all these charts? I want to be able to use these in my custom apps.

thanks
Kay

Answer (score 0):

Source code for these reports is not available. These reports are generated by a first generation analytics engine. Some of those charts can be installed in custom pages from AppCatalog - but those are thin wrappers around the same report, and the underlying code for those is not available.